# Kinect Null Depth and Color Frame

Tags: xna, null, frame, kinect

I am developing a game using `XNA Framework 4.0` and `Kinect 1.6 SDK`. My code is using color, depth and skeleton data so I am using `AllFramesReady` event.

When I run the game and there is someone to detect, the function that is triggered by `AllFramesReady` event extracts the image and the skeleton data of the person and sets the attributes of my `Player` class.

Problem is, this code used to work perfectly in the past. But even though I didn't make any changes to my code, it is not working now. I tried on other computers and it worked. But the same code is not working on my computer.

When I debugged, I saw that `DepthFrameEventReadyArgs` and `ColorFrameEventReadyArgs` have a member called `isInvalid` and they are set to true. Because of this, when I use:

`DepthImageFrame depthVideoFrame = mainFrame.OpenDepthImageFrame();`

... I get a null `depthVideoFrame`. Same applies for color frame.

Here is where i initialize Kinect (in `Initialize`):

```
if (KinectSensor.KinectSensors.Count > 0)
            {
                kinect = KinectSensor.KinectSensors[0];

                EnableColorStream(kinect);
                EnableDepthStream(kinect);
                EnableSkeletonStream(kinect);

                kinect.AllFramesReady += new EventHandler<AllFramesReadyEventArgs>(kinect_AllFramesReady);
                kinect.Start();
            }
```

Enable methods:

```
void EnableColorStream(KinectSensor ks)
        {
            ks.ColorStream.Enable(ColorFormat);
            colorWidth = ks.ColorStream.FrameWidth;
            colorHeight = ks.ColorStream.FrameHeight;
            colorVideo = new Texture2D(graphics.GraphicsDevice, ks.ColorStream.FrameWidth, ks.ColorStream.FrameHeight);
        }

        void EnableDepthStream(KinectSensor ks)
        {
            ks.DepthStream.Enable(DepthFormat);
            depthWidth = ks.DepthStream.FrameWidth;
            depthHeight = ks.DepthStream.FrameHeight;
            depthVideo = new Texture2D(graphics.GraphicsDevice, ks.DepthStream.FrameWidth, ks.DepthStream.FrameHeight);
        }

        void EnableSkeletonStream(KinectSensor ks)
        {
            TransformSmoothParameters tsp = new TransformSmoothParameters();
            tsp.Smoothing = 0f;
            tsp.Correction = 0.1f;
            tsp.Prediction = 0.1f;
            tsp.JitterRadius = 0.1f;
            tsp.MaxDeviationRadius = 0.1f;
            ks.SkeletonStream.Enable(tsp);
        }
```

In `kinect_AllFramesReady` I am using something like:

```
using (ColorImageFrame colorVideoFrame = imageFrames.OpenColorImageFrame())
{
   ...
}
using (SkeletonFrame skeletonFrame = imageFrames.OpenSkeletonFrame())
{
   ...
}
using (DepthImageFrame depthVideoFrame = imageFrames.OpenDepthImageFrame())
{
   ...
}
```

As I debug, I saw that `colorVideoFrame` and `depthVideoFrame` values were `null`, because `isInvalid` member is set to `true`. When I run other programs using depth and color data, they run normally but only this one is not working. I am currently out of ideas. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please include the code you are using to initialize the Kinect and capture events.

Comment: I've added some code to the main message.

Comment: I've not been able to try the code out yet, but have you tried using the individual `FrameReady` events instead of `AllFramesReady`?

Comment: No I haven't but I don't think that's the problem. As I said before this code used to work perfectly. I am pretty sure that there is no problem with the structure of the code.

I think the problem is "isInvalid" attribute being true. I wonder what causes it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could give this a try. As one of the commenters suggested, you may be getting this error since you only ever call AllFramesReady. You may need to call it in the SkeletonFrame, ColorFrame, and DepthFrameReady event handlers individually. Ex.

```
void DepthFrameReady(object sender, DepthImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
{
 DepthImageFrame imageFrame = e.OpenDepthImageFrame();
 if (imageFrame != null)
 {
   // Do your business here
 }
}
```

The reason I am going with this answer is because the Kinect for Windows SDK documentation states, "A frame of color data in a new ColorImageFrame object, or NULL if the data is no longer available." and since your machine may be set up differently than other machines your code worked on, any variation in the K4WSDK or your compiler could drastically change how your program operates after it is compiled.

As far as why this is not working, it might be a compiler issue on your machine. Did you check that you have the same version of the compiler in VS? Is it the same version of VS? Also, have you checked that all of the appropriate libraries and includes are present on your machine? If you really wanted to determine the root cause, you could step through on the working machines and compare to your own.